# How to stop motor after a desired time?

Tags: arduino-nano, motor

I am trying to stop a dc motor after a desired amount of time !! And the motor starts upon settling on a condition !! From that very moment i want my motor to just run for 5 seconds and stop!! Below is the pseudocode:

```
 #define max 150
 #define min -150
 #define pin1 3
 void setup()
    {
        Serial.begin(9600);
         mpu.initialise();
     }
   void loop()
     { 
        x= some_accelerometer_values;
         If (x>250)
            { 
                analogWrite(pin1,255);
                delay(5000);
                exit(0);
             }
      }
```

I tried using millis() but it starts time with execution of program and i can't get to implement it just before the motor starts running!

Comment: 1. Don't use `exit(0)` on a microcontroller. There is no OS to take charge after the end of the program. Better use an infinite loop, if you want to end the program and do nothing more

Comment: 2. Have you understood the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example, that comes with the Arduino IDE? I explains the use of `millis()` rather good. You take a timestamp (value of `millis()`), when the start condition arises, and then you calculate the difference between the current `millis()` value and the timestamp and compare it to the 5s (5000ms).

Comment: Thumbs up for the exit(0); information !! I didin't knew that, nor it was working with it !! But the millis(); is troublesome !! Its counting time since the program started !! And not since the motor started !!

Comment: @HrithikBaishakhiya You can use a variable to save the time when the motor started. Then always check the difference between now, and when the motor has started. And if the difference is >= then 5 seconds, it turns off

Comment: `But the millis(); is troublesome !! Its counting time since the program started !! And not since the motor started !!` ..... how do you boil  an egg for 3 minutes by using a clock, without using a timer?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you turn your motor on with `analogWrite(pin1, 255);` just write `analogWrite(pin1, 0);` after the `delay(5000);`.

And using `exit(0);` isn't as bad as people will most likely say. Using exit(0) is the same as `cli();` + `while(1)`. So it disables interrupts and stucks your code in a while loop till your reset the arduino.

Comment: But if x remains greater than 250 for a while then it will run until x < 250!!

Comment: @HrithikBaishakhiya since you used exit(0); you want your code to only run once. And if you write analogWrite(pin1, 0); before the exit(0) your motor will turn off. Then the program will stop and not ask about whether x is greater than 250 or not.

Comment: @HrithikBaishakhiya if() is triggered by a condition, and will only be executed once per loop()

Comment: I respect your effort !! But its not recommended to use exit(0); as written in some contexts and suggest by chrisl above!! I am little confused here !!

Comment: @HrithikBaishakhiya as of I know, exit(0); disables interrupts and throws the arduino into a while(1) loop. I just tried it on my arduino-uno. It's pretty much a loop() but with disabling interrupts.